# Spinner is not working in android

Tags: android, spinner

Spinner is not working. Here is my code:

```
public class second extends Activity{   
    Spinner spin;
    String[] str;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);        
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
        str = new String[] {"bike","car"};      
        spin.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, str));    

        spin.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String data= spin.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            Toast.makeText(second.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }    
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see what your logcat says ?

Comment: 08-02 11:54:48.009: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.ex/com.my.ex.second}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I am just showing the data selected in spinner by toast.

Comment: I think you have to set OnItemSelectedListener not OnItemClickListener.. try replacing that.. and see the results...http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only mistake you made is you have set different event listener..

The Listener `OnItemClickListener` is for `ListView`..

For `Spinner` you have to set `OnItemSelectedListener` ..

Try replacing `OnItemClickListener` to `setOnItemSelectedListener` like :

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener (new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String data= spin.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Toast.makeText(second.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
```

Comment: How is this valid? you are setting an set a OnItemSelectedListener with a OnItemClickListener?

Comment: I tried that piece of code you posted. It throws compiler errors. My "understanding" is that you need spin.OnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() ...
And OnItemSelectedListeners do not have the callback you mentioned. They only have OnItemSelected() and OnNothingSelected()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html

Comment: @Kartik it's throwing compile errors because you're using OnItemClickListener instead of OnItemSelectedListener. Dunno why OP accepted the answer.

Comment: @dpk Thanks for notifying. Corrected.

Comment: I've corrected the code so that it can compile, hopefully my edit will be accepted

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here,

```
 spin.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String data= spin.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Toast.makeText(second.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
```

Try replacing it as follows,

```
 spin.OnItemSelectedListener (new OnItemSelectListener() {

    public void onItemSelect(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String data= spin.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Toast.makeText(second.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
```

Comment: Once again, how are you setting an OnItemClickListener to an OnItemSelectedListener? This is not valid

Comment: OnItemSelectedListener is an interface that has two(2) methods that need to be implemented, namely:
onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) and 
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the problem in your oncreate() method:

```
spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
```

You assign the result to spinner which is a local variable/reference here. main.spinner class field is still null. This is why you have NullPointerException in calculate() method.

Replace the line above with:

```
this.spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,androidBooks);
spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
 List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("--Qualification--");
    categories.add("High School");
    categories.add("Higher Secondary/PUC");
    categories.add("Diploma");
    categories.add("Degree");
    categories.add("Master Degree");


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    R.layout.spinnertext, categories);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[Check Out on this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm)